# Adding javax.servlet (et al) to Tomcat 10 webapps/[app]/WEB-INF/lib

Tags: odata, tomcat10

I have a Java8 app that I have been using for years that provides and consumes web services, including  Olingo OData. Vulnerabilities are compelling me to upgrade to the latest - Java11 and Tomcat10. I am able to migrate the web services to jakarta, except Olingo.

I have arrived at a solution, that so far runs without a problem, but I am curious if anyone else has tried this.  I added the jars for javax.servlet (4.x) to the webapp lib folder. I also reconfigured my app by isolating references to javax to a single jar file. The isolated jar file provides an API that is void of any reference to javax.  The maven projects build without errors, the jar files get packaged with the deployment, and Tomcat10 appears to find and load the 4.x classes. My preference would be to upgrade Olingo to jakarta, and avoid this work-around.  But at the moment, that is not an option.

Comment: That is not possible, use Tomcat9 instead. Tomcat 10 and Tomcat 9 are equal but Tomcat10 is for JakartaEE whereas Tomcat 9 is for JavaEE.

Comment: I ended up using eclipse transformer to migrate the bytecode from javax to jakarta.